# Unable to use the authgaurd based on the subscribed data

Tags: angular

```
if (localStorage.getItem('localcache') && this.authservice.getAdmin().subscribe(data => {

    return data['status'];
  }, error => {

    return false;
  })) {

  return true;
} else {
  this._router.navigate(['/login']);
  return false;
}
```

I am trying to set the authgaurd return value based on the server response,but here if the error occurs at the server means like 403 etc the authgaurd doesn't working,Kindly give some example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return an `Observable` in order for the auth guard to wait for your `getAdmin` call, also you can return an `UrlTree` directly for the guard to redirect to the login route:

```
return this.authservice.getAdmin().pipe(
  map(({ status })=> !!localStorage.getItem('localcache') && status),
  catchError(() => of(false)),
  map(isAdmin => isAdmin || this.router.parseUrl('/login');),
);
```